# transferFrom function showing error

Tags: solidity, remix

transgerFrom function is showing error and always falied . please help.

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
    require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
    if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    }
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to comment out     //require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);

Comment: But balances[_from] >= _value is necessary for check that from account has token for transfer

Comment: I know it's just to see if your transaction isn't respecting this requirement. So if it works check your tx.

Comment: I am getting error because of (allowance >= _value). So could you explain why it is giving error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before being able to call transferFrom on a token contract the account holding the balance of those tokens must have called `approve` to give the account calling `transferFrom` an allowance.

If the transaction is failing here:

`require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);`

that means that either the account you are trying to send tokens from has an insufficient balance or that it hasn't given you such an allowance by first them calling `approve` on the token first.

Answer (score 0):

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

What is your allowance variable coming from? What does it equal?

Your logic is also very poor. If you're having problems, set up the various moving parts into different functions and have them call each other.